# Logstash REST Filter - limit the speed

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Created a logstash config file that takes data from MSSQL and push it to ElasticSearch, I am using Logstash REST Filter to enrich the data

```
filter {

rest {
request => {
  url => "http://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone? 
  key=[KEY]&format=json&by=zone&zone=Europe/%{city}"
  method => "post"   
}

json => true
sprintf => true 
target => "test"                    

}
}
```

My question is:

Is there a way to limit/slow down the logstash as the sample API i am using is returning me errors that I am making too many calls?

Comment: Perhaps rethink the need to make this API call on every event.  Cities don't normally change/move timezones that often.  Grab a snapshot of the data, and use the translate filter to add the extra data.  Update the cache periodically via cron, and logstash will reload the file for you.

Comment: I know, I was using this API as a test to see how i can enrich the data. I agree with you regarding taking the snapshot of a data and running it then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [filter sleep plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-sleep.html) in Logstash which should be useful to rate limiting.

Example of config:

```
filter {
  rest {
   # rest related
  }
  sleep {
    time => "1"   # Sleep 1 second
    every => 10   # on every 10th event
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done exactly as per your example, however it does not work. I still get error from API that the call was made 2 quick. My settings are: Time = 2 / every = 1.

Comment: @Lemon increase the Time option, perhaps? Also see if reducing the number of logstash workers has any effect.